# Probability with colored balls

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have a bag with $ x $ red balls and y blue balls. I randomly draw two balls at the same time without replacement, then keep repeating this process until the bag is empty. Call a pair of balls "colorful" if it is made up of one red ball and one blue ball. The expected number of colorful pairs is $ 2020.$ What is the number of possible pairs of $(x,y)$?

I was thinking to set up an equation, like $ 2xy/(x+y)^2-x-y = 2020, $ but couldn't get any farther than that. Could someone help me answer this?

Comment: Sounds like a contest question.  Can you provide a source?

Comment: What is the thinking behind your equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of getting RB or BR on the first draw is $$p=\frac{2xy}{(x+y)(x+y-1)}$$ This is also the probability of getting RB or BR on any draw.

There are $n=\frac12 (x+y)$ pairs in each run. The expected number of colourful pairs in any run is 
$$np=\frac{xy}{x+y-1}=2020$$
$$y=\frac{2020(x-1)}{x-2020}=2020+\frac{2.2.5.101.3.673}{z}$$

$z=x-2020$ must be a factor of the numerator. We must have $x, y \gt 0$ so $z \gt 0$. Also $x+y$ must be even. Assuming $x \le y$ possible values are :

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 z & x & y \\ \hline
  2 & 2022 & 2041210 \\ \hline
  6 & 2026 & 681750 \\ \hline
 10 & 2030 & 409858 \\ \hline
 30 & 2050 & 137966 \\ \hline
 202 & 2222 & 22210 \\ \hline
 606 & 2626 & 8750 \\ \hline
 1010 & 3030 & 6058 \\ \hline
 1346 & 3366 & 5050 \\ \hline
\end{array}

A further 8 pairs are generated by switching $x, y$.

Therefore **there are $16$ possible pairs of values $x,y$.**

Comment: The question wasn't about the number of pairs of balls but about the number of possible pairs of $(x,y)$ :-). So your answer is "$2$".

Comment: There are other integer solutions, including some in which $(x+y)$ is even.

Comment: @DanielMathias Thank you for pointing this out. I shouldn't have relied on Wolfram. Is my method faulty? Is there a unique solution? (Apart from the trick solution.)

Comment: Your approach is correct. Rewritten, the equation is $y=\frac{2020(x-1)}{x-2020}$, which has 24 integer solutions with $2020<x<y$, 8 of these have $x+y$ even. These are ordered pairs, so there are $16$ pairs $(x,y)$ that meet the conditions.

Comment: @DanielMathias Ah now I understand the final sentence of the question!